# Plotting positive and negative pixels of image separately on subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, plot, pixel

Suppose have an image like this, that consists of two images, 1 and 6 which are kind of superimposed on each other, if you look closely at it.

So, I need to visualize each of these digits separately by having all positive pixels of original image in one image, and all negative pixels in the second one. Is there any way to achieve that in python using matplotlib.pyplot without messing up with the structure of the image?  Basically, I need all the white color pixels to be plotted separately from the black color pixels. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set all values above or below some threshold to `nan`, such that they won't appear in the final image.

The following code leaves out the range between 0.4 and 0.6 completely. The yellow background is chosen to show that there are no pixels in that area.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread("grayscaleimage.png")[:,:,0]

white = np.copy(img)
white[white<0.6] = np.nan

dark = np.copy(img)
dark[dark>0.4] = np.nan

fig = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(224)

ax0.imshow(img, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="Greys")
ax1.imshow(white, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="Greys")
ax2.imshow(dark, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap="Greys")

for ax in (ax1,ax2):
    ax.set_facecolor("gold")

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Here is the test image used in the above: 
[image] (right click, save as...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked pretty well! I had to change some values though, but I got the point. Could you also share where did you get your testing image? it looks much sharper and it is very relevant to my ML perceptron algorithm that I am implementing

Comment: I added the test image. It's created via inkscape by placing a white 1 and a black 6 on gray background.